# Grep searching specific pattern

Tags: regex, linux, grep, gnu

I have a text like:

```
94.98 bla bla bla bla
98.456 bla bla bla bla
104.984 bla bla bla bla
194.982 bla bla bla bla
```

And I do a Grep:

```
grep 94.98 $text_file
```

But I obtain this:

```
94.98 bla bla bla bla
194.982 bla bla bla bla
```

How can I make the search exclusively specific and force "grep" to only search "94.98" ??

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^` for line begin

```
$ grep '^94.98' foo
```

or `\b`s for word breaks.

```
$ grep '\b94.98\b' foo
```

Comment: note this would also match lines stating with `94.98hello`. Better use `-w` or a `\b` anchor as described in the duplicate.